# Rolling back a remote Git repository

Tags: git

I have a remote Git repository, and I need to roll back the last `n` commits into cold oblivion.

Comment: "into cold oblivion", LOL on that one, sometimes that's just where some commits should go. 

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You can use `git revert <commit>…` for all the n commits, and then push as usual, keeping history unchanged.

Or you can "roll back" with `git reset --hard HEAD~n`. If you are pushing in a public or shared repository, you may diverge and break others work based on your original branch. Git will prevent you doing so, but you can use `git push -f` to force the update.

Comment: You can rollback to a specific commit by using: `git reset --hard [sha1]` where sha1 is the commit hash identifier.

Comment: You cannot use get reset --hard in a remote repository since there is no working directory. The original question only states there is a remote repo, there is no mention of a local repo.

Comment: just a note, git push -f will force push all local branches to their remotes

Comment: Please keep in mind, that using `revert` will cause your feature branches to be treated as "already" merged. That's because these branches *are* actually being merged. But the changes were reverted. Solution: _Cherry-pick_ or _revert the revert commit_.

Comment: @Benedikt does the `reset --hard` also cause the feature branches to be treated as already merged?  My assumption is it wouldn't (where `revert` would).

Comment: @MarcusLeon `reset --hard` is totally fine. But applying this on a remote branch may cause troubles on team members' local branches. Make sure you align with your team and notify everyone so that they can update they local branch.

Comment: If you instead of using `git push -f` use `get push ---force-with-lease` you will avoid accidentally overwriting commits that have been pushed after your last `pull`.

Comment: @pisaruk where to find the [sha1] to rollback a commit, is it something like "17f30ee4e8d35b7a54d12615e508f78532611097"

Answer (score 37):

elmarco is correct... his suggestion is the best for shared/public repositories (or, at least public branches).  If it wasn't shared (or you're willing to disrupt others) you can also push a particular ref:

```
git push origin old_master:master
```

Or, if there's a particular commit SHA1 (say 1e4f99e in abbreviated form) you'd like to move back to:

```
git push origin 1e4f99e:master
```

Answer (score 11):

Fortunately I was in a position to use [Pat Notz's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/588615/1828051) which completely removed the unwanted commit. However, initially I got the error

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@gitrepo.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected*
```

But adding the force (`-f`) option overwrite this error

```
git push -f origin 52e36b294e:master
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have direct access to the remote repo, you could always use:

```
git reset --soft <sha1>
```

This works since there is no attempt to modify the non-existent working directory. For more details please see the original answer:

[How can I uncommit the last commit in a git bare repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624881/how-can-i-uncommit-the-last-commit-in-a-git-bare-repository/5627799#5627799)

Comment: Why would `--soft` even be necessary? You could probably do the same thing with just plain `git reset`, without the mode flag.