# Rolling back last commit on remote

Tags: git, push, git-push, git-reset

I want to do exactly what it was asked in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647301/rolling-back-local-and-remote-git-repository-by-1-commit).

I tried the answer but it didn't work. Here is what I did (I am on master):

Checking if my local is equal to the remote:

```
> git fetch
> git log ..origin/master
> git log origin/master..
```

Both empty output. Then:

```
> git reset HEAD^ --hard
HEAD is now at *SHA1* *Commit message*
> git push -f
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/master (you should pull first)
To *Remote path*
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to '*Remote path*'
```

Comment: Your remote has been set up to disallow what you're trying.  Do you have access to that machine?

Comment: @CarlNorum is that the effect of `receive.denyNonFastForwards` configuration? In this particular case I don't have access to the remote. There is anyway to do this without accessing it? And, if I do had access, what would be the better approach? Doing git reset directly on the machine? Altering the configuration momentaneously?

Comment: If you don't have access to the remote to change the `denyNonFastForwards` setting, and can't convince the admins of the remote to do so for you, your next best bet is to probably just `git revert HEAD`. That will create a new commit that reverses the effects of the last commit and get you back to the state at `HEAD^`, but depending on your perspective, it leaves a bit of a "wart" on your history...