# Remove remote commit in git

Tags: git

I can't find working solution for my problem:

How to remove commit in local and also in remote repository.
Here is one [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647301/rolling-back-local-and-remote-git-repository-by-1-commit#). But when I try this I can go back with `reset` command in my local repository. But I can't push it. The error message says:
`remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/master (you should pull first)`
But after `pull` my master points again to the commit that I want to remove.

Can you help?

EDIT - my try:

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD^1
HEAD is now at 1c50f9c good commit

$ git push -f
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/master (you should pull first)
To E:/reps/gf.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'E:/reps/gf.git'
```

Comment: I tried with `git push -f ` and `git push --force`. It doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your remote repository likely has a setup that disallows non-fast-forward pushes on the server side. You have two options:

1. Contact the server administrators, explain your case, and ask them to (temporarily) rescind the no-fast-forward-push policy, with something like `git config receive.denyNonFastForwards`. (You will still need the `-f` flag to push.)
2. Use `git revert` instead of `git reset`, and push the resulting commit. Both the commit and its inverse will be visible, but sometimes that cannot be avoided. Unless the original commit contains sensitive data, this should be a big deal—git commits get reverted all the time. If the original commit does contain sensitive data, see option 1.

Comment: I have git remote repository on the other hard-drive, so I can config it. I tried with command: `git config --system receive.denyNonFastForwards false`, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Finally it works when I used `git config receive.denyNonFastForwards false`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @bLAZ I've updated the answer to include the config invocation.