# Completely revert a repo and local files to one particular commit state

Tags: git, github

so I want to remove everything that I have worked on today, both from the git repo and also my local.

i have a commit from yesterday, which I want to revert to. Could i remove the repo and then clone the repo from a specific commit?

thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just call `git reset --hard <sha of commit from yesterda>` ?

Comment: ... and then `git push -f`? (WARNING: this will lose later commits)

Comment: If other developers have pulled the changes, see [Rolling back local and remote git repository by 1 commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647301/rolling-back-local-and-remote-git-repository-by-1-commit).

Comment: and I want to lose the later commits, so that's good :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do reset to make changes to local repo and forcefully push to remote repo.

```
git reset --hard <commit>
git push --force <remote> <branch>
```

**Warning:** Reseting and forcefully pushing will delete the commit history.

Replace `<commit>`, `<remote>` and `<branch>` with the appropriate names like a `SHA-hash`, `origin`, and `master` respectively.

Here, `<commit>` is the `SHA` hash of the last commit upto which you wanna reset.

Comment: I'm getting this error whilst trying to run git reset -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline' ?