# 'origin/master' have diverged , not able to commit the code . Don't want to retrieve the last commit file

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-commit

I am getting the Message when trying to commit the code :

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://xyz@bitbucket.org/xyz-iphone.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I don't want to go back the the last commit . The file which i am using is taken from previous commit .

How can i commit in same repository with / without changing the branch ?

Comment: git pull origin master

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I had some trouble in source file in last commit . so i downloaded my source file from few previous commits. Now i am not able to commit in same repository.

Comment: Are you trying to `push`? Do you want to get the changes of the remote in your current branch? As it stands it's not clear what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't want to get back the current branch git-hub changes . Just want to save my work on same repository .

Comment: You want to override the changes on the server?

Comment: Exactly Yeah.. Thats what i a trying to do .

Comment: This should be able to help you: [Rolling back local and remote git repository by 1 commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647301/rolling-back-local-and-remote-git-repository-by-1-commit). It is only considering a **SINGLE** commit but can be easily applied to multiple.