# Conflicts on BitBucket after reseting head on local repo

Tags: git, bitbucket

Hi have a situation where some bad code was pushed and I needed to use git to reset the head to a previous commit.

I have managed this fine using the following:

```
git reset --hard eglhfghjlfgh0fgh78097fgh987fgh

git push origin branch_name -f
```

However, after my local git repo I have a further 3 repo's (dev, stage and prod).

This pushes fine to the dev repo, but using bitbucket, I do a pull request and I'm prevented from merging because of a conflict, so I can't get the reset code to the stage and prod repo's

Is there any way to make the subsequent repo's know I've reset the head at the bottom level so allow the merges?

Sorry if the terminology is wrong - I'm fairly new to this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rolling back local and remote git repository by 1 commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647301/rolling-back-local-and-remote-git-repository-by-1-commit)

Comment: @KeillRandor the instructions in this answer are the same as those that I've followed already. It's going up from dev to stag where I get the problem