# How to get rid of last commit in git?

Tags: git

I pushed up a change but it looks funny in stash compare view. I want to get rid of my last commit and redo it.

I tried both of these

```
git reset --hard HEAD~
git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

what does get rid of my commit but then it wants me to do a pull before I can do a push and I get all the changes back.

Comment: `git push -f` rewrites the history on remote branch, effectively replacing the history with you local version - thus dropping the unwanted commit.

Comment: do I do this with the command I showed or just alone?

Comment: `git reset HEAD~1` removes the commit from your local branch. `git push -f` then pushes that to remote counterpart.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rolling back local and remote git repository by 1 commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647301/rolling-back-local-and-remote-git-repository-by-1-commit)