# git delete pushed commit and remove history entry

Tags: git, commit

I have pushed some changes to the repository.

I want to delete the last commit from the repository and permanently remove the history entry as well.

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rolling back local and remote git repository by 1 commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647301/rolling-back-local-and-remote-git-repository-by-1-commit)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try:

```
git checkout <branch> // replace branch with a name of the branch you worked on
git reset --hard HEAD~1 // this command removes the latest commit
git push --force-with-lease origin <branch> // push the changes to the remote
```

If nobody modified the remote while doing the operation above your push will be accepted, otherwise it may be rejected. Further steps are dependant on if you can use `-f` instead of `--force-with-lease`. If so do it, but it will overwrite other's changes. If not - it can't be done without changing the history.