# In git, what's the simple way to squash mulitple commits in a head before rebasing it onto another head with ONLY 1 resolve conflict?

Tags: git

I have the following 2 branches, A should be rebased on top of B:

```
(Ancestor) -> A1 -> A2 -> A3
          \
           -> B1
```

I'm trying to squash all commits in A into 1 commit:

```
(Ancestor) -> B1 -> A123
```

However when I use git rebase with squash commit command, git still tries to rebase one commit at a time, so it start rebasing A1, ask me to resolve conflict, then rebase A2, as resolve conflict again, ... This waste a lot of time in rebasing branches.

My idea rebase would be to squash A1, A2, A3, directly, then only ask to resolve conflict between A3 & another head. I can do it manually with 2 git commands, but this is also not convenient. Is it possible to do it automatically with one command?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *number of commands* is not really that important, I think, because you can always put however many commands it takes into a script or alias.  What matters is the *amount of interaction* needed.

Thus, I think what you want is a soft reset style squash commit (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5203843/1256452) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6869737/1256452)) followed by a rebase.  To get it down to one interaction, you will need to automate the message made for the first squash commit, probably by concatenating the three (or however many) to-be-squashed commits, and then use an interactive rebase with the [sequence editor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29094904/1256452) set to a script of your own that replaces the `pick` command with `reword`.  Actually writing each of these pieces is something I leave to you, but I'll note that:

- `git show --format=%B --no-patch --no-notes <commit>` will get you the full commit message for the given commit.
- Replace `show` with `log` and a commit range to get several messages; or use `git rev-list <range>` to get the IDs printed to standard output, then loop using `show`, to allow you inject your own (varying) text between each.  (For fixed text, possibly including additional `%` conversions, you can simply use the `--format` argument.)
- The sequence editor can be any script in any language; it just needs to open the interactive rebase commands file, modify it, and write it back out to the file.

Comment: Looks like you are right. Its not supported natively in git, but I'm using intelliJ IDEA and recently did a lot of merging pull requests, maybe this can be a plugin feature