# How to merge all previous commits into a single commit?

Tags: git, github

**Context:**
Started project on GitHub and have been experimenting with git commands. The history of the project is untidy.

**Question:** How can I remove all history and replace all commit messages with something along the lines of "Uploaded initial version of project source"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This option will allow you to keep all your configuration files for the project
`git reset --soft <sha_of_initial_commit>`
`git commit -a --amend -m "initial commit"`

Comment: +1. Another use for `git reset --soft` added to the existing list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203535/practical-uses-of-git-reset-soft

Comment: @Andy I have tried this and I get a long list of filenames with `create mode ...` Nothing appears to happen. I tried adding `git push` at the end of those commands, but still nothing. Am I missing something? thanks

Comment: You will get that long list as it is adding all the files back into your repo. What does the output of `git push -f` say? Did you check github and see if you got the results you wanted?

Comment: @Andy `push -f` worked perfectly. What does this do differently?

Comment: Since you re-wrote your history, `push` requires the `-f` flag to make sure that you know you are changing history.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `.git` directory.

`git init`
`git add .`
`git commit -m "Initial commit"`
`git push origin master`

Comment: If this was subversion, the answer would have involved sacrificing a cow at some point.

Comment: The push won't work, how is there an _origin_ if the repo was just initialized?

Comment: Also, assuming you had added `origin`, it would need to be a forced push.