# Git: how to delete all commits except last one

Tags: github

I load on git some project which contains some personal data. Now I changed all lines and commit it. Now I need to erase all commits except last one to prevent loosing personal data.

Comment: The best way is to merge all commits into one, which is answered by this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425725/how-to-merge-all-previous-commits-into-a-single-commit?rq=1

Comment: finally, I just bought account to hide this code

Answer (score 14):

Given that your main branch is called master, and you want to remove all commits except the last one from your master:

1. `git checkout --orphan tmp`
2. `git add . --all`
3. `git commit -m "Init."`
4. `git push origin tmp`
5. *On your remote git repo select tmp as main branch*
6. `git branch -D master`
7. `git push origin :master`
8. `git checkout -b master`
9. `git push origin master`
10. *On your remote git repo select master as main branch*
11. `git branch -D tmp`
12. `git push origin :tmp`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to remove the .git directory.

Open the Linux Terminal.
Move to your repository and:

```
cat .git/config
```

Note the url variable and the name of the branch:
$my_url
$my_branch

```
rm -rf .git

git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"

git remote add origin $my_url
git push -u --force origin $my_branch
```

I made this [bash script](https://github.com/claudiofsr/rust-sped/blob/master/git-cleanup.sh) which can be improved. Awaiting suggestions.