# Move commit to a new branch without touching index or working tree

Tags: git, version-control, commit

A parent question here: [Move the most recent commit(s) to a new branch with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563/move-recent-commit-to-a-new-branch)

I have taken over a project that has a working tree full of files that still need organizing - some refer to work tasks in progress; others are completed. I have a recent commit of completed work, but this is not destined for production. How can I discreetly move it into some new branch without screwing up my current tree?

```
I'd like to change

Working tree - A - B - C - D - E

to

Working tree - B - C - D - E
              /
             A
```

Comment: Is `A` the newest/most recent commit?

Comment: @Mat - in this case yes, but a general solution would be awesome if you have one!

Comment: Then the question you link to is a duplicate of this one, the scenario is exactly the same as far as I can tell. What's missing?

Comment: Lots of uncommitted files in staging and working tree.

Answer (score 0):

With `checkout -b "name of branch"` you will create a new local branch.

Comment: That doesn't look right. This doesn't move the commit, and won't it change my working tree?

Comment: this will create a branch that is in exactly in the same condition as the one that you are working on now.

Answer (score 0):

```
git branch tmp
git reset --soft B
```

Will move the HEAD (and only HEAD)  to `B` (after marking `A` with a '`tmp`' branch)

See "[Practical uses of `git reset --soft`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5203843/6309)" for more on `reset --soft`.

Answer (score 0):

First write A's SHA1 somewhere, you'll need it later.

`git checkout <E's SHA1>`
`git rebase -i HEAD~6` (6 is commit distance from E to A plus one)

Delete A's line in the editor and save.

Now you have this:

```
 Working tree - B - C - D - E
```

Now we want to create a branch to A, starting from B:

`git checkout <B's SHA1>`
`git branch BAbranch` (or whatever you want to call it)
`git checkout BAbranch`
`git cherry-pick <A's SHA1>`

And now you have this:

```
 Working tree - B - C - D - E

                  \

                     A
```