# Reset Git to commit without changing HEAD to detached state

Tags: git

I'd like to restore the files of the git working copy to a given commit, without setting that commit as the HEAD commit.

If I git checkout to a given commit I obtain a detached HEAD, and after commiting changes, the commit tree would look something like:

```
A
|
B
|
C  
| \
D  E
```

While the behaviour I'd like to obtain is:

```
A
|
B
|
C
|
D
| <- git command so my files are restored to C, but my HEAD still points to D
E
```

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't commit be on top of `C`, not `B`? And how do you plan to handle merge conflicts?

Comment: Not sure what you are really trying to achieve, and a lot less sure how you will handle merge conflicts/working tree changes, but have you tried `git checkout <commit> .`?

Comment: Yes, it should hang from C, my bad. I'll edit the question. My intention is to replace all the files of my workspace with the files from commit 'C', WHITOUT setting C as my head commit. If 'C' is setted as my HEAD commit, it will be in a detached head state.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This should do it:

```
git reset --hard C
git reset --soft D
```

First you reset the `HEAD`, index and worktree to `C`.
Then you reset `HEAD` (and only `HEAD`, as explained in "[Practical uses of `git reset --soft`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203535/practical-uses-of-git-reset-soft/5203843#5203843)") to `D`.

Note that a commit at this point would create a *new* commit with `C` content, replacing `D` by a `D'` looking like `C`.
That changes the history, and is not much different than a simple `git reset --hard C`.

Another option would `git revert C` on top of `D`, but `D` would still be visible in the history, which might be what you don't want.

Comment: Commit `D` will not be replaced (as far as I can see). Also `reset --hard` will remove any working tree changes (but that might be necessary)

Comment: Exactly. Works like a charm.

Comment: Just brilliant! Exactly what I needed to get back the changeset from a different branch as unstaged delta in the working tree of another branch.

Answer (score 28):

VonC answer requires you to do a roundtrip. You can achieve the same thing with a single 'git checkout'

`git checkout C ./`

Note that you have to provide `./` otherwise git will actually check out the specified branch or commit.

Comment: @JamesJohnston: This answer doesn't handle the case where files have been deleted or moved in branch C, it simply leaves them there.

Answer (score 7):

The plumbing commands for this (for anyone scripting this sort of thing) are:

```
git read-tree C
git checkout-index -f -a
```

Although for some reason I can't fathom, when I run this from a script, I also have to do the following after the above commands, otherwise I get an error about patches not applying to the index:

```
git update-index -q --refresh
```

Comment: The part about `git update-index -q --refresh` just now helped me with something completely unrelated. Thanks :-)

Comment: Nice.  Note that this leaves the files from `C` staged in the index (`read-tree` puts them in the index and `checkout-index` updates the working tree), whereas the other answers change the working tree only.