# Why explicitly call git reset --soft before git reset (--mixed)

Tags: git

In the git docs (and numerous SO threads) this reset approach is recommended:

```
$ git reset --soft HEAD^ ;# go back to WIP state  <2>
$ git reset                                       <3>
```

> .2. This removes the WIP commit from the commit history, and sets your working tree to the state just before you made that snapshot.
>
> .3. At this point the index file still has all the WIP changes you committed as snapshot WIP. This updates the index to show your WIP files as uncommitted.

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html

Obviously that's fine, but it seems that these two commands could be replaced by

```
$ git reset HEAD^
```

(which is equivalent to)

```
$ git reset --mixed HEAD^
```

which should reset both the HEAD pointer and the index to the previous commit.  Is there in fact a difference between the result of this command and the previous two?  If not, is there some reason to prefer the two-stage process?  Or was it just done that way in the docs to explicitly illustrate the behavior of --soft?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there doesn't seem to be any difference.
It is more to illustrate the `git reset --soft` (i.e. moving HEAD only, which can [have other more practical uses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5203843/6309))

`git reset HEAD` is for "unstaging", and a simple `git reset HEAD^` does both (move the HEAD, and unstage, no need for `--mixed`, since it is the default option)

---

Here is a quick test to see what that looks like:

Before (you just switch back to feature, where you committed a "`wip`" -- work in progress):

```
C:\Users\VonC\prog\git\test\r\r3>gl
* 6ac95bd - (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) fix in master (2 minutes ago) <VonC>
| * fd8d97d - (HEAD, origin/feature, feature) snap WIP (3 minutes ago) <VonC>
| * 16066dd - f1 (3 minutes ago) <VonC>
|/
* e8ad96f - f1 (3 minutes ago) <VonC>
```

The reset itself:

```
C:\Users\VonC\prog\git\test\r\r3>git reset "HEAD^"
Unstaged changes after reset:
M       f
```

That gives you the status:

```
C:\Users\VonC\prog\git\test\r\r3>git st
# On branch feature
# Your branch is behind 'origin/feature' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
#   (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   f
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

log after `git reset HEAD^`

```
C:\Users\VonC\prog\git\test\r\r3>gl
* 6ac95bd - (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) fix in master (6 minutes ago) <VonC>
| * fd8d97d - (origin/feature) snap WIP (7 minutes ago) <VonC>
| * 16066dd - (HEAD, feature) f1 (7 minutes ago) <VonC>
|/
* e8ad96f - f1 (8 minutes ago) <VonC>
```

---

In two steps, you would have seen the following log after the `git reset --soft HEAD^`:

```
C:\Users\VonC\prog\git\test\r\r2>gl
* 6ac95bd - (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) fix in master (65 seconds ago) <VonC>
| * fd8d97d - (origin/feature) snap WIP (89 seconds ago) <VonC>
| * 16066dd - (HEAD, feature) f1 (2 minutes ago) <VonC>
|/
* e8ad96f - f1 (2 minutes ago) <VonC>
```

You index would still reflect what was staged for `wip`:

```
C:\Users\VonC\prog\git\test\r\r2>git st
# On branch feature
# Your branch is behind 'origin/feature' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
#   (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   f
#
```

The reset would then unstaged, bringing you back to the same stage than a `git reset HEAD^` would have in one step:

```
C:\Users\VonC\prog\git\test\r\r2>git reset
Unstaged changes after reset:
M       f

C:\Users\VonC\prog\git\test\r\r2>git st
# On branch feature
# Your branch is behind 'origin/feature' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
#   (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   f
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.  And certainly there are other uses for git reset --soft.  (In the most basic case, there's often simply no reason to reset the index as well, in which case --soft will save you having to re-stage the files.)  But good to know for sure that there's no need for the two-stage process if you're planning to reset the index as well anyway.  Why type more characters than necessary?

Comment: @NathanStretch I agree. It is more to give a choice (in case you committed a work in progress composed of evolutions that should be staged, and *other* evolutions that should be staged *separately*: then, you unstage everything, and `git add` what you want to commit first in your wip.