# squash more then two commits in sourcetree?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, squash

I have a large number of commits, about 20, that I've done since my last push to origin/master.  I have never had more than one branch, master, and all commits were done on master.  How can I squash all 20 commits into one commit, preferably using sourcetree?  I want to do this so I can just push one commit to origin/master.

In sourcetree I have figured out to use the interactive rebase command in the repository menu.  It brings up the exact list of commits I want to squash.  I tried hitting the squash button repeatedly until it shows one commit containing all of them.  But when I hit OK I end up with only the two most recent commits squashed.  So even though the dialog seems to show it can squash multiple in practice I can't get it to work.

Comment: This question has also been [asked at Atlassian Answers](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/301907/interactive-rebase-in-sourcetree-windows-doesnt-work-properly-at-all).  No solution yet.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Easier solution (than a rebase):

Select the "origin/master" commit in the log entry, click on "`Reset <branch> to this commit`".

[image: http://i.imgur.com/nWDzb6k.png]

Use the default mixed mode.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/bTaS5KD.jpg]

Then add and commit: all your changes will be registered again in *one* new commit, that you will be able to push.

See [`git reset` Demystified](http://git-scm.com/blog/2011/07/11/reset.html) for more.

Comment: Thanks, that did it.  So I guess it moved all changes since origin into the working copy?  Is this correct?

Comment: @mark-hahn it reset the index while keeping your working-tree intact, allowing you to register again *all* modifications in a new commit.

Comment: Oh, I see.  It put them into the index which is what was committed.  I'm used to committing directly from the workspace. Maybe I still don't understand.  I'll keep studying this.

Comment: @mark-hahn yes, http://git-scm.com/blog/2011/07/11/reset.html is a good resource to understand `git reset`.

Comment: Can I use soft mode like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5201642/538763)?  What's the difference?

Comment: @crokusek yes, it is generally used to squash commits. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/5203535/6309