# How to linearize “splintered” merging history in Git?

Tags: git, merge, rebase, cherry-pick

I have read through the basics of the [git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/) trying to linearize the  branch red from with the branch blue got merged into. To easier review the history I try to have only one branch and no junction. What options do I have to do this and what is best?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31121213/how-to-linearize-splintered-merging-history-in-git) answer suggests to `reset --soft`, but here demo assumes it grew a lot since the merge.
It is ok to have the branch blue changes be added to red before `af`  or preferably after `9c` commit.

```
* 5356e62 vimdiff solved
* c1ccf86 red forward
*   51fbd33 Merge branch 'blue' into red
|\  
| * 96575dc new file
| * 1d7f531 some line and blue branch 3
* | 9cc3291 new file
* | 92569c6 another commit
* | f8d3ab2 blue branch 3
|/  
* af8b651 init
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Caveat* -- **ALL** methods of doing what you ask move a ref "backward" (effectively removing some commits); if those commits have been shared with other developers, it creates a problem.  See the `git rebase` documentation regarding recovering from upstream rebase, and understand that while this was documented in terms of rebase it applies to all history editing.

To the extent that `git reset --soft` was a reasonable answer to the previous question, it's equally reasonable here.

```
git checkout 5356e62
git reset --soft 9cc3291
```

and now all the changes from 1d7f531 onward appear as staged changes, so

```
git commit
```

creating a new commit that "squashes" the old commits into one.

At this point if you have a branch pointing to 96575dc, then it will appear to be unmerged.  OTOH if the parent branch was previously the only branch that could reach 96575dc, then 96575dc is now unreachable; but that's ok if you don't want that detailed history, because the relevant changes are in your new commit.

A somewhat more general solution is `merge --squash`, and still more general would be `rebase --interactive`