# Can't find `HEAD` in git rebase conflict?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-merge-conflict

I am trying to rebase in order to squash commits, and I get a conflict:

```
<username>:~/path/to/director$git rebase -i HEAD~6
error: could not apply 0111a7a... <commit message>

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply 0111a7acsadd9a9d98a9003a560a390a50a22afa3af546f42101... <full commit message>
```

Then, I do the following to find the conflict:

```
find . -name "*.py" -exec egrep ".*HEAD.*" {} \;
```

since I know that I only changed python files, I use the `*.py` globbing.  However, no results show up!  Is there a way to find exactly what the problem is?

`git status`, and `git diff` are both clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the answer below, I want to note one thing: if you just want to squash a series of commits into a single commit, the easiest way is usually just to combine `git reset --soft` with the single desired commit.  See [this answer by Chris Johnsen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5201642/1256452) and [this answer by VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5203843/1256452), and note VonC's last bullet-pointed paragraph.

---

We can't tell for sure what is happening, because you haven't shown us enough information, but here's a common scenario in which `git rebase` tells you that it cannot apply some commit, yet there's also no modifications shown by `git status`.  This is **not the same** as your case (you're rebasing your own commits on your own `HEAD~6`, which makes this less likely), but again we haven't seen enough information from you, so I present this as an example instead.

Let's say that you're rebasing a series of two or more commits.  The first fixes the spelling of the word `word` on line 3 of a text file.  The second and any subsequent commits do other with other files.  These changes were made on branch `bran`, but since then you've run `git fetch` and/or decided to move these to branch `master` or whatever.

Meanwhile, it turns out someone else *also* fixed the spelling of the word `word` on line 3 of that text file, along with the spelling of the word `spelling` on line 12.  Your fix is therefore a subset of their fix.  It's not the *exact same* fix—you fixed just one word, they fixed two—but your fix cannot be applied as the word `word` is already spelled correctly on line 3 of the text file.

Git can't<sup>1</sup> understand that this is OK.  It's up to you to figure out that your fix, while it's different from the "upstream" fix you're rebasing on, is no longer needed.  *In this case* (but not in other cases) you should simply skip the commit.

Here's an example session where this has occurred:

```
$ * abda13a (master) fix two words
| * 9e7ed64 (HEAD, bran) add a file
| * 144d5a6 fix one word
|/  
* ac7be27 initial
```

Let's take a look at commit `144d5a6`:

```
$ git show bran^
commit 144d5a66949cdd40fd92b0846d5b0ce00ebcdd8c
Author: [redacted]
Date:   [redacted]

    fix one word

diff --git a/README.txt b/README.txt
index c37e4c4..983e649 100644
--- a/README.txt
+++ b/README.txt
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 This readme file
 has at least one
-wurd
+word
 that is
 misspelled.
 There may be
```

Now let's look at the tip-most commit of `master`:

```
$ git show master
commit abda13a47f5b5d968a09eedaf5cc573ba35a3dee
Author: [redacted]
Date:   [redacted]

    fix two words

diff --git a/README.txt b/README.txt
index c37e4c4..867d98f 100644
--- a/README.txt
+++ b/README.txt
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 This readme file
 has at least one
-wurd
+word
 that is
 misspelled.
 There may be
@@ -9,7 +9,7 @@ words, since
 the point of
 this file
 is to allow someone
-to fix the speeling
+to fix the spelling
 of any
 of the misspelled
 words.
```

Now let's rebase the current branch (which is `bran`) onto `master`, but interactively:

```
$ git rebase -i master
[the editor comes up with both commits selected as `pick`]
[I exit the editor with the same `pick`s]
The previous cherry-pick is now empty, possibly due to conflict resolution.
If you wish to commit it anyway, use:

    git commit --allow-empty

Otherwise, please use 'git reset'
rebase in progress; onto abda13a
You are currently rebasing branch 'bran' on 'abda13a'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
Could not apply 144d5a66949cdd40fd92b0846d5b0ce00ebcdd8c... fix one word
```

(This is with git 2.3.7, incidentally; older versions don't even note that the cherry-pick has become empty, and simply complain that the commit can't be applied.  It's not clear to me why it's advising `git reset` either; that is not necessary at this point.  However, git 2.3.7 is now rather out of date; I should upgrade.)

---

<sup>1</sup>This actually depends on other things.  With git 2.3.7, it's now smart enough to detect this case for a *non-interactive* rebase.  Using the initial setup from above:

```
$ git rebase master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: fix one word
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M   README.txt
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
No changes -- Patch already applied.
Applying: add a file
$ git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
* c8f1815 (HEAD, bran) add a file
* abda13a (master) fix two words
* ac7be27 initial
```

In this case, the non-interactive rebase figured out that my "fix one word" was redundant with "fix two words" and simply skipped it, so that the final sequence of commits on `bran` is really just the one remaining commit, with "fix two words" on `master` as its parent.

Comment: OKay, thank you.  I suppose part of my confusion was that I don't understand the difference between `git rebase --skip` and simply deleting the commit during and interactive rebase:  `git rebase -i HEAD~6`.

Comment: If you delete it from the initial instructions, git won't attempt to cherry-pick it at all.  If you use `git rebase --skip` (perhaps after some amount of `git reset`-ing, maybe that's what the message was about even though it was redundant in that particular case), you're telling git to abandon it at that point, after attempting to cherry-pick it but failing.

Answer (score 1):

normally `git status` should show you a file in conflict. You shouldn't be searching for **HEAD** but for **<<<<<<**, **======** or **>>>>>>**.

Since you say that `git status` is clean, it is possible that your commit has become empty. You can check what is in the commit using

```
git show 0111a7a
```

if your commit has become empty, you should skip it, using

```
git rebase --skip
```

Comment: I'm rebasing onto HEAD in order to squash the commits.  Do you think that might be why it doesn't show up in `git status`?

Comment: Well, the commit isn't empty, since `git show 0111a7a` shows some changes.  But, I don't see `<<<<<<` or the like, so it isn't clear to me how to edit that.

Comment: this is strange, normally git should try applying the commit, and leave unresolved commits marked as such, with <<<<< and >>>> markings...

Comment: maybe try aborting and starting again?