# difference between soft reset and amend commit in git

Tags: git, git-reset

I am learning git and came across git soft reset and amending a commit in git. I see both of them serving the same purpose. Any notable difference between the two. Please let me know since I am not able to see any difference between the two.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Practical uses of git reset --soft?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203535/practical-uses-of-git-reset-soft)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`git commit --amend` will change your most recent commit on the current branch by adding any staged changes you've made so far to it and prompt you to change the commit message.

`git reset --soft` will actually remove commits from the current branch but keep the changes as uncommitted changes that need to be staged and recommitted.

Comment: in addition to that, git reset allows you to go over multiple commits, and amending only ever affects one single commit.

Comment: True, although I did say "remove commits" plural. :P