# How to merge branches sequentially with clear history using git?

Tags: git, merge, rebase, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

I have branches `develop` and `upgraded` that I want to merge. Branch `upgraded` comes from `develop` but there are about 50 new commits (mainly merges with other branches) on it and much more changes in `upgraded`. So I want to merge `develop` into `upgraded` sequentially (commit by commit), because there are API changes which need to be updated and merge conflicts. But when I do it by simply merging commits from `develop` it creates new connection for every commit on the graph. I don't really want 50 unnecessary graph paths...

How can I avoid this crazy graph connections? 
Most gladly using Atlassian Sourcetree GUI.

[image]

Comment: Why are you doing this one by one??

Comment: Because it's much easier to catch bugs. As I said there were framework api changes and the develop branch still uses old api - it needs to be updated...

Comment: Have a look at [`git imerge`](https://github.com/mhagger/git-imerge). I've never been driven to it so I don't know much beyond that it looks like an exact match for what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you've already done the work and just want to squash all the merges together, see [Squashing a sequence of small merges from master into my branch with git while keeping reference to master?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40344424/1256452)  (This uses the command line; it's probably impossible in a GUI, since GUIs are designed to make it easy to do the usual thing, and rarely take unusual things into account at all.)

If you want to do this in the future, [`git imerge`](https://github.com/mhagger/git-imerge) (as mentioned in [jthill's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40351639/how-to-merge-branches-sequentially-with-clear-history-using-git#comment67958264_40351639)) does the job.  Again, it runs from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Create a secondary branch `develop-rebase` which point to the same tree as `develop`. You keep the original `develop` branch in case anything goes wrong.
 Then, rebase `develop-rebase` on top of `upgraded`, which applies each commit sequentially. Do it interactively so that you have a chance to test after each commit.

Hopefully, you will obtain a clean state and apply some patches during this process.

You can stop here if it is enough for you. But if you want a merge from `develop` to `upgraded` without intermediate rebases, you can take the diff from your new `develop-rebase` and `develop`, apply it on top of `develop` then get rid of `develop-rebase`.

Then, make different atomic commits from that patch that explain how you modified `develop` to make it mergeable with `upgraded`, and merge.