# Git interactive rebase - Squash the latest merge commit with the previous N commits

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, rebase

My current git commit history looks like -

```
git log -4 --graph

*   commit B
|\  Merge: D C
| | 
| | 
| * commit C
| |
* | commit D
|/  
|
|
* commit E
```

The merge commit B contains some additional changes apart from the (D + C) merge change.

I want to squash the latest merge commit B with the past 2 commits C and D.

I want my commit history to look like -

```
* commit A (B+C+D)
|
|
|
* commit E
```

Comment: Use `git reset --soft`: see the accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/5203535/1256452 (you don't want to set up `.git/MERGE_HEAD`, just do the soft reset  to commit `D`, and then make new commit `A` with `git commit`).

Comment: @torek I did a soft reset and committed the changes. My local commit history changed as expected. But I was not able to push it to my remote repository. I get the message - 'Everything up-to-date'.

Comment: What precisely was your `git push` command, and if you used `git push` with no additional arguments, what is your `push.default` setting and what is the upstream set to for the current branch? (If your `push.default` is unset, what does `git --version` produce?)

Comment: Using git reset --soft <commit hash> caused a detached head issue when the push was made to to the branch.
 
git reset --soft origin/develop followed by commit and push did the trick. I was able to overcome the detached head issue.

Comment: `git reset --soft` does not detach HEAD. If it is *already* detached, though, it will reset HEAD as usual, without moving any branch *name*, meaning you continue to have a detached HEAD. That would explain the behavior you saw.