# What's the Use Case for Git SOFT reset?

Tags: git

I'm trying to wrap my head around the different Git methods (Revert, Switch/Chekout, Reset)

Why would I want to do a Mixed or Soft `reset`?
I'm a VC newbie so maybe I'm missing something.
I thought the point of the above was to change my local files to some other version (from Git repo)

Comment: Already answered (for the "soft" part) in http://stackoverflow.com/q/5203535/6309

Comment: You mean a mixed or soft `reset`, don't you?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "soft revert". This terminology is specific to Git (Mercurial uses the word "revert" differently, for instance), but in Git, *revert* means, more or less, "make a *new* commit that undoes something from a *previous* commit". You are looking at *reset*, which is a significantly more complicated command (I sometimes argue that it should be at least two or three separate commands, instead of one big "reset").

Comment: The point of a soft reset is *not* to change the local files.  Rather, it changes the state of the index.

Answer (score 0):

I have these aliases in my `.gitconfig`.

```
# Undo the last commit, but leave it in the working copy
redo = reset --soft HEAD^

# Throw out all work up to the last commit
clear = reset --hard HEAD

# Undo the last commit
undo = reset --hard HEAD^
```

As you can see, I use `reset --soft HEAD^` if I want to do the last commit over. The [`git-reset` docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) also mention this use case in their examples. There is an overlap between this and `git commit --amend`.

Answer (score 0):

The use case is for those times when you want to reset the index, but you don't want to change any working files.  For example, suppose you've made 3 changes in file `foo` and done `git add foo`.  Then you realize you don't want to commit all three changes, but you only want to commit one of them.  So you do a `git reset` followed by `git add --patch foo` to select the hunk you want to commit.