# Git - Copy branch without history

Tags: git

I got a very messy branch, with a lot of commits, that I used for some experimentations.
It turns out that I want to keep a large part of this work, but its really need to be refactored and cleaned up.

So I'd like to copy all these modifications to a new branch, without history and without committing.
That way, I could clean it up, start a proper feature branch and remove the messy one.

```
Before:

          D - E - F
         / 
A - B - C


After:

          D - E - F
         / 
A - B - C
         \
          DEF (uncommitted)
```

I didn't find the way to do that, help would be really appreciated.

Thanks :-)

Comment: Note: until you actually *commit* this new `DEF` commit—the `git commit` after the `git reset --soft` in VonC's answer—the new branch name, whatever may be, will identify commit `C`. The uncommitted files will be in your work-tree and perhaps also have already replaced the commit-`C` copies of file in your index. (This depends on whether you have used `git reset --soft` as n VonC's answer, or `git reset --mixed` / default as in knittl's.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `git reset --soft` C, from your current branch: that would preserve the working tree

```
git switch oldMessyBranch
git switch -c newBranch

# Or, in one line:
git switch -c newBranch oldMessyBranch

# Then:
git reset --soft C
git commit -m "new squashed branch"
```

Note: with [Git 2.23+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309), you should use the new (still experimental) command [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch).

From there, you can add the content and create a new branch.

As I mentioned in "[Practical uses of `git reset --soft`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5203843/6309)"

> So, each time:
>
> - you are satisfied with what you end up with (in term of working tree and index)
> - you are not satisfied with all the commits that took you to get there:
>
> `git reset --soft` is the answer.

Comment: @torek `oldMessyBranch` indeed. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

`git reset` to the rescue!

```
git checkout -b newbranch F
git reset C
```

This will create a new branch with the content of F, then set the branch's tip to commit C with all changes still in the working tree. Without any arguments, it defaults to `--mixed` mode, so the changes will be *unstaged* and you can them add and commit them as you like.

(With `--soft` all changes are automatically added to the staging area)

Answer (score 1):

Say you want to copy the changes to branch `foo`. You have several options.

```
git diff C F > foo.patch
git checkout foo
git apply -3 --reject foo.patch
```

or

```
git checkout foo
git cherry-pick -n D
git cherry-pick -n E
git cherry-pick -n F
```

or

```
git checkout -b temp C
git merge --squash F
git commit
git checkout foo
git cherry-pick temp
git branch -D temp
```

There are some other variations. The key is to get the diff first and then apply the diff.