# How can I update my current master branch with an old git tag after comparing diff between them?

Tags: git, github, git-diff, git-tag

I want to check the diff between current master branch and an old git tag (lets say, tag1).

After checking the differences, I want to discard the changes and merge tag1 into my master branch because tag1 is currently running in production and I want my master to be updated with it.

How can I do these tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`git revert`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert), assuming `tag1` is an older commit on the `master` branch:

```
git revert tag1..master
```

Or you can use [`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) (with the [`--soft` option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5203535/6309)):

```
git switch master
git branch tmp master
git reset --hard tag1
git reset --soft tmp
git add .
git commit -m "commit tag1 content to master"
```