# How can I uncommit the last few commits from a branch in a bare repo?

Tags: git

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624881/how-can-i-uncommit-the-last-commit-in-a-git-bare-repository) seams to deal with rewinding the commits from the master branch.  Can I use a similar `git reset --soft` command on a branch in the repo or should I be trying to make sense of `git revert`?

Ultimately I'd like to rewind two branches by two or three commits (not just the last) in the bare repo.

Comment: Do you mean that you're _pushing_ to a bare repo and you'd like that (remote) bare repo to have it's branches rewound?

Comment: @Pal Notz: Yes.  Its my repo so I'm not worried about goofing other users.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm still not clear where the repo is. You say it's bare but you must have a non-bare somewhere too.

**If you just want to rewind local branches** then you want to use `git reset`. So if you have a local branch `beta` then you can rewind it like this:

```
$ git checkout beta
$ git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

This will drop 3 commits: `HEAD`, `HEAD~1` and `HEAD~2`. These will get garbage collected in about 90 days so you ***can*** get them back if needed.

**If you have a remote repo named `origin` (that is bare) and you'd like to rewind the branch over there**, then you can do this via a *forced push*.  Let's say you pushed 3 commits on `beta` before they're ready. You can keep them in your local project but remove them from the remote bare repo like this:

```
$ git push -f origin beta~3:beta
```

This can be harsh to others using that repository but it sounds like you're okay with that.

**If you *only* have a bare repo** then you can forcibly reset the branch like so:

```
$ git branch -f beta beta~3
```

Note: this also works for the first case of rewinding local branches. Again, this is unfriendly to anyone using this repo.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what you want to do.  `git revert` will generate *new* commits in your repository to reverse the changes made by your selected commits.  This is nice from a change tracking perspective -- you can see what was reverted and why, and you can always rethink your decision later.

You can run `git reset` (without `--soft`, which is only meaningful in a working copy) to simply reset the repository back to a previous state.  This discards the commits after your selected commit, so you'll lose that history forever.  If there are people with remote working copies of the repository, they will suddenly find their working copies out of sync (and they may inadvertently re-introduce the changes when they run `git push`).

If it's your own repository and you're not sharing it with anyone else, `git reset` is fine.  Otherwise, `git revert` is probably the better choice, both because it leaves a trace in the repository history and interacts well with remote working copies.

Comment: Definitely a `git reset` then.  Does `git-reset <SHA-HASH>` leave all the commits on that branch after `SHA-HASH` unreferenced? (i.e. deleted?)