# How can I delete git commits without resetting the directory?

Tags: git, commit

**First of all:** Yes, I searched for this topic here and found a [lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/how-can-i-delete-a-git-commit) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-the-last-git-commit) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624881/how-can-i-uncommit-the-last-commit-in-a-git-bare-repository).

None of them was what I needed for my special use case though. Before you mark this as a duplicate, read my background information please.

---

**Background story:**
I’m currently working as an independent app developer and freelancer. I’ve developed a framework that I’m selling to different costumers. While developing this framework, I was using the raw source code and committed it to one of my costumers Git Repos. I never thought about selling it **at that point in time**. It grew in complexity and function and I’ve got a compiled version of it now.

**Now I would like to be able to delete some commits without rebasing the project to remove the source code because many people would have access to it.**

I searched for quite some time and couldn’t find a working solution.

Comment: So you want to delete some history, but not touch the history because others have cloned it? Do you see a contradiction?

Comment: I want to delete a specific part of history in a way that it will be also removed when somebody pulls the new version of the history. Is that possible?

Comment: Don't think you can do it. As you don't want to rebase and, dreadfully, many have already forked (or using it), history cannot be altered. Otherwise, I would have suggested, pull a branch prior to your oldest unwanted commit and cherry pick each commit you want to go in to it.

Comment: It is a local Git in a controlled environment. Around 3-5 people are working with it. So Forking is not a problem.

Comment: If the environment is small and the code is not leaked outside, you can simply tell the people to stop for a second, do your rebase/cherry-pick whatever, force push it and have them replace their branch with the new one. Make sure no one has unpushed/unmerged work.

Comment: This sounds like a workaround I could live with… Do you want to add this as an answer, so that I can accept it later, if it works?

Answer (score 1):

I have a theory that may work in your case.

Current status:

```
master: A ---- B ---- C ---- D ---- E ---- F 
                                           ^
                                           HEAD
```

Lets say, you want to delete commits `B` and `E` but keep `C`, `D` and `F`

Do `git reset HEAD~1`
`git stash`
Repeat previous steps till `HEAD` reaches `A`

Now `master` looks like this:

```
master: A                    Stash stack looks like:  
        ^                      B
        HEAD                   C
                               D
                               E
                               F
```

Checkout a new branch `temp`:

```
master: A                   Stash stack looks like
        |                      B
        |                      C
  temp: A                      D
        ^                      E
        HEAD                   F
```

Now, you can selectively `pop` each stash on `temp` (resolving conflicts if necessary). Note that when conflicts occur, the stash is not removed from the list. You have to explicitly call `git stash drop`

`git stash pop stash{revision number}`
`git stash drop stash{revision number}` if there was a conflict.
`git stash drop stash {unwanted revision}`

`temp` should look like this:

```
master: A 
         \
temp:     ---- C ---- D ---- F 
                             ^
                             HEAD
```

Merge or rebase `temp` with `master`. The `master` should look like this after rebase and fast forward merge:

```
master: A ---- C ---- D ---- F
                             ^
                             HEAD
```

NOTE: In step one, another (quicker?) way to do is: `git reset <SHA of A>`. Then you can do interactive stashing using `git stash --patch` and selectively stash chunks of your changes.

Comment: Pretty much like an interactive rebase, no?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work

```
git reset HEAD^
```

use HEAD without --hard or --soft flag

Comment: This is different than what OP wants.