# How to completely reset github repository in Pycharm?

Tags: git, github, pycharm

I'm trying to completely delete and re-upload my GitHub repository. I'm using Pycharm's GitHub integration, and for the life of me I can't figure out how to make Pycharm forget I ever had GitHub repo setup and just start from scratch.

I even tried moving the .git files to another location and clear Pycharm's cache but the damned thing still remembers it has a Github repository setup even though it doesn't actually exist on GitHub anymore.

Anyone knows how to make Pycharm forget ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to completely empty a remote Git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922104/is-it-possible-to-completely-empty-a-remote-git-repository)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### To unlink the git repo to GitHub,

entering `git remote -v`  will list the remotes configured.

```
origin  git@github.com:user/repo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:user/repo.git (push)
gitlab  git@gitlab.com:/user/repo.git (fetch)
gitlab  git@gitlab.com:/user/repo.git (push)
```

the one with github.com (`https://`  or `git@`) points to the remote to GitHub. (here `origin`)

To remove a remote, you can,

```
git remote remove origin
```

or in older versions of git,

```
git remote rm origin
```

To add a new github repo as the remote, you can

```
git remote add <name> <repo url>
example. git remote add origin https://github.com/myusername/myproject.git
```

#### To reset the branch to the initial (or any specific) commit,

in the `version control` > `log`, scroll down to the initial (or any specific) commit

[image: pycharm version control]

and click `Reset Current Branch to Here...`

then select hard

[image: hard reset git pycharm]

and press reset. (this is an irreversible change)

to push the changes in the local repo to the remote repo (after resetting to local to desired commit), run push with `-f` which forcefully updates the remote. make sure the remote branch is not protected to `push -f`.

```
git push -f <remote> <branch> 
example. git push -f origin master
```

#### To delete all `.git` stuff and startover, you may run

```
sudo rm -rf .git/
```

at the repo root  (this will delete the .git directory, irreversible change) and then run `git init`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. I'm trying to reset the git repo to the current local changes. I.E Delete the remote repo (which I already have done from the GitHub website) and reupload all the local files from scratch. It seems the hard reset you suggested will do the exact opposite and erase and local changes so the would match the initial commit.

(I'm on windows) I also tried erasing the .git folder in the project root. Pycharm still remembers everything...

Comment: I have updated the answer, try pushing the repo to remote with `-f`