# Gitea can't fetch repositories

Tags: linux, git, raspberry-pi, gitea

I installed gitea (If someone don't know it, it's an opensource fork of gogs) on my raspberry pi. I tried it under user pi and under user git. In user pi the gitea was installed in `/home/pi/gitea` and in git it was installed in `/home/git`. In both situation the repository directory was in the install root.

I made a new repository with the webui and I tried 2 remotes with both installation.

```
rpilocal = pi@192.168.1.125:/home/pi/gitea/repositories/uname/repositoryname
rpilocal2 = pi@192.168.1.125:uname/repositoryname
rpigitlocal = git@192.168.1.125:/home/pi/gitea/repositories/uname/repositoryname
rpigitlocal2 = git@192.168.1.125:uname/repositoryname/repositoryname
```

When I tried to push on `rpilocal2` and on `rpigitlocal2` I got the following error message:

```
git push rpigitlocal2 master
git@192.168.1.125's password: 
fatal: 'feralheart/leltar.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

and when I tried to push with `rpilocal` and `rpigitlocal` the push was success, BUT in the webinterface I stil got the "Make a new repository or push existing with CLI".

What's the matter?

Answer (score 0):

I was working-with a test setup of `gitea` on a VPS<sup>**♣**</sup> and encountered what may have been the same problem. After poking around with various tests, I found a workaround that is working for me. In case it could help *you*...

#### What was already working

In my case, asking `gitea` to create a new `git` repository with an initial "readme commit" was working fine. I could `clone`, add new commits, and `push`. The new commits appeared after the first one in the `gitea` web UI.

#### What wasn't working

If I asked `gitea` to create a repository without an initial commit<sup>**†**</sup>, `gitea`'s web UI would not reflect the push of a commit history, i.e.

```
user@client:~/projects$ mkdir myCode
user@client:~/projects$ cd myCode
user@client:~/projects/myCode$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/user/projects/myCode/.git/
user@client:~/projects/myCode$ echo "testing 1 2 3" > file.txt
user@client:~/projects/myCode$ git add file.txt
user@client:~/projects/myCode$ git commit -m0
[master (root-commit) f9d8e7] 0
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 file.txt
user@client:~/projects/myCode$ git remote add origin git@server:gitea_repos/owner/myCode.git
user@client:~/projects/myCode$ git push -u origin master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 210 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@server:gitea_repos/owner/myCode.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
user@client:~/projects/myCode$
```

`git` would report success and `git@server:gitea_repos/owner/myCode.git` would continue to function as a remote but the `gitea` web UI would continue to display the "empty repository" help page instead of the repository browser<sup>**‡**</sup>.

#### Work-around strategy

Because new commits were registering on repositories that started non-empty, [it occurred to me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4924146) that `gitea` might notice the change if `git` overwrote the stub commit history of a new project with the complete commit history of another project<sup>**↯**</sup>. To try this, follow:

**3 Easy Steps:**

1. In the `gitea` web UI, create a new repository. On the `New Repository` creation page, be sure to check the box next to `Initialize this repository with selected files and template` before clicking `Create Repository`.
2. On your workstation, add this new stub as a `remote` to the local `git` repository with the desired commit history.

   ```
   user@client:~$ cd projects/myCode
   user@client:~/projects/myCode$ git remote add gitea git@server:gitea_repos/owner/myCode.git
   ```
3. Overwrite the `gitea`-generated stub-commit with the intended material.

   ```
   user@client:~/projects/myCode$ git push -fu gitea master
   Counting objects: 97, done.
   Delta compression using up to 32 threads.
   Compressing objects: 100% (95/95), done.
   Writing objects: 100% (97/97), 55.53 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
   Total 97 (delta 45), reused 0 (delta 0)
   To git@server:gitea_repos/owner/myCode.git
    + a1b2c3...d4e5f6 master -> master (forced update)
   Branch master set up to track remote branch master from gitea.
   user@client:~/projects/myCode$
   ```

**Note that, for Step 3:**

- `-f` is for **force**: this empowers `git` to perform the (otherwise prohibited) "commit tree overwrite"
- `-u` is for **set-upstream** - this connects local branch `master` through the remote-tracking branch `gitea/master` to the master branch managed by `gitea`

#### Follow through

This strategy is something of a hack and I suspect it leaves a few things undone. E.g. you might want to push branches and tags up to `gitea`. (My tests haven't taken me this far.) Consider `--all` for branches and `--tags` for tags:

```
user@client:~/projects/myCode$ git push gitea --all
user@client:~/projects/myCode$ git push gitea --tags
```

While YMMV, I wish you luck!

---

**Footnotes:**

**♣** - I am working with `gitea-1.4.2-linux-amd64` on `Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS` hosted at `virmach.com`.

**†** - `git` uses the term "empty repository" when referring to a repository w/o commits but, in the internal API used by `gitea` to access `git` features (and, occasionally, by `gitea` community members), the term "bare repository"<sup>**☥**</sup> is used.

**☥** - `git` uses the term "bare repository" when referring to a repository *not* embedded (as the directory `./.git`) in the root directory of a "working tree". Bare repositories are frequently used as a canonical copy for collaboration and are stored on (and accessible from) a server. E.g. the 'github' service. Sometimes these directories are named with the schema `project_name.git`

**‡** - I tried a number of setup variations, asked around on `irc` channel `#gitea`, and poked around in the code. All I can conclude is that some difference in the `git`→hooks→`gitea` chain (varying between empty and non-empty repositories) is responsible for this problem on my VPS.

**↯** - Before this, I thought of replaying the history of the desired project over the new stub but this `rebase` operation is a desperate hack: all the commits get new `sha` checksums and, essentially, all developers would have to clone-in again as if working on a new repository.