# git - made a push to the wrong repository, how to remove?

Tags: git

Edit: Regarding **This question may already have an answer here:**, note that the title of that question refers to undoing a commit, not a push. I don't think SO should be reinforcing the frequent confusion between the two within git. Also is a question with 22 different answers going to be the best reference?

I created a new project `lambda` in a repository X, under the dev branch, then did `git add`, `git commit` and `git push`.

Turns out it doesn't belong in that repository, but in repository Y, under its dev branch. Now people looking at X are seeing a bunch of stuff that doesn't belong.

How do I remove that push from X dev? Note that I don't want to remove the whole branch from X, just the bad push I did.

If it helps, everything is self contained in that project, no other projects were altered. Just deleting lambda project and any history of it would be okay too.

After searching, I think what I want to do is [undo a git push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270514/undoing-a-git-push). But I'm not sure I understand the solution.

### git log

This is what `git log` is telling me.

```
$ git log
commit 0c9ac8b157222995d3414b84e7ce1b3e1adf5560
Author: Clueless <clueless@initech.com>
Date:   Fri Feb 14 10:01:38 2014 -0400

Initial commit of lambda.

commit bdd142c778f0c43141cf48d60e4ee0bef018e1c0
Author: Not Clueless <notclueless@initech.com>
Date:   Thu Feb 13 12:50:39 2014 -0400

update red with latest and greatest

commit f1047816fa7b201de7f798e6026b8b29a1bf8f75
Author: Also Not Clueless <alsonotclueless@initech.com>
Date:   Wed Feb 5 15:48:07 2014 -0400

update green with latest and greatest

etc...
```

So do I want to use?

```
git push -f origin 0c9ac8...:<???>
```

But don't I want to make `bdd142...` be the origin? Also what do I specify for ??? ?

### Diagrams

Perhaps a couple of diagrams might help:

What it looks like now:

```
X-repo
+---master-branch
|
+---dev-branch---+---red-project
|                |
|                +---green-project
|                |
|                +---blue-project
|                |
|                +---lambda-project <-- doesn't belong
|
+---other-branches

Y-repo
+---master-branch
|
+---dev-branch---+---alpha-project
                 |
                 +---beta-project
                 |
                 +---gamma-project
```

What it should look like:

```
X-repo
+---master-branch
|
+---dev-branch---+---red-project
|                |
|                +---green-project
|                |
|                +---blue-project
|
+---other-branches

Y-repo
+---master-branch
|
+---dev-branch---+---alpha-project
                 |
                 +---beta-project
                 |
                 +---gamma-project
                 |
                 +---lambda-project <-- belongs here
```

Comment: This is almost certainly a duplicate of [How to undo the last Git commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/)

Comment: @Ajedi32 - In that question, it isn't mentioned that a push was made to a remote repository.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right. There are several answers to that question that do address that situation though. There's also these: [How can I remove 'git commit' after 'git push'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459080), [Git: Rolling back a remote repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588414/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I undo a \`git commit\` locally and on a remote after \`git push\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459080/how-can-i-undo-a-git-commit-locally-and-on-a-remote-after-git-push)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest is to do:

```
git revert 0c9ac8b157222995d3414b84e7ce1b3e1adf5560
```

This will undo the commit locally. Then:

```
git push
```

This will update the remote repository. The commit will still be in remote, just not in the way any more.

Comment: Tried it. Seems to work, and confirmed at the remote end their side is cleaned up, too. Thank you!