# Github pull request shows too many changes/commits

Tags: git, github, version-control, pull-request

We have two branches: `develop` and `master`.

For some reason when I create a PR of `develop` --> `master`. It shows a whole list of previous commits and changes even if I've made only a single line change in `develop`.

Also, it will say "Can't automatically merge" when from the command line I'm able to merge `develop` into `master` without a problem.

Any idea what might be going on? Previously it was working fine for us.

EDIT: Here's what it looks like when we try to merge `develop` to `master`. Only the most recent commit is new. The others were merged previously:
[image]
And the output of `git log --oneline --decorate --all --graph`
[image]

Comment: What changes are included in those extra commits? Are they just merge commits? Please post the output of `git log --oneline master..develop`. Also possibly of interest is `git log --oneline --decorate --all --graph`.

Comment: @ScottWeldon Added - let me know if there's anything else that would be helpful.

Comment: @ScottWeldon ps added a bounty

Comment: [Please don't post your console output as an image](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3933332), but instead copy/paste the output and [use Markdown's code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). (The first image is probably okay, but the second one doesn't add anything over raw text.)

Comment: @ScottWeldon I would argue otherwise in this instance: the colors both for branches and decorated refs are helpful. You are right, I would still add the text form, but in a pastebin external link though, to not clutter the question too much.

Comment: @VonC Fair enough.

Comment: @EvanHobbs The PR diff is what I would expect judging by your `git log` output, because `master` is a ways behind `develop`. I also notice several commits like `Develop -> Master (#xxx)` (e.g. commit `25e931c`). What is your normal process? How were those commits generated?

Answer (score 15):

Your git log shows that there is a lot of commits in the `develop` branch that don't exist in the `master` branch. The pull request correctly shows a list of these commits, that can be merged into the `master` branch.

To list all commits from the `develop` branch that are not part of the `master` branch you can use the command `git log master..develop`. This should match the list you see in the pull request.

From your git log it looks like `develop` has been merged into `master` previously. But since these merge commits are no longer in the `master` branch, is it possible that someone have done a reset of the master branch to an eariler state? Possibly to roll back changes if you have a deployment to an environment synced to the `master` branch?

### Solution

To get `master` in sync with `develop` again:

1. Checkout `develop` and `pull` to make sure the branch is up to date
2. Do the same thing with `master`
3. Merge `develop` into `master`
4. Resolve the conflicts
5. Push the `master` branch

Now `master` will be in sync with `develop` again and the list of commits in `develop` that `master` is lacking should be empty. List these commits with `git log master..develop`. Your next pull request will only contain the commits you do after this merge.

### Further investigation

If you want to investigate further how you ended up in this state you can use `reflog` to see what changes that have been made to the `master` branch. Fore example if one of the more recent commits in `develop` previously has been part of the `master` branch.

```
git reflog master
```

If you want to do this you can do it before you merge the branches so you can see how the history looked before the fix.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I got the op correctly. As I understood you have a single commit in the `development`branch so here is my try.
I am considering the problem that your development branch is not in sync with master

1. revert back the development branch commit while keeping the local changes
   git reset --soft HEAD^  # Assuming the last commit is yours

   At this point your local changes will stay in your machine as-is

   Now push this to git .. you may try force push at this point.
   You can take help from here
   [Rolling back a remote Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588414/rolling-back-a-remote-git-repository)
2. Stash the local changes so that you can get these changes in future: 
   git stash

   At this point your development branch is clean and has no local changes
3. Now switch to master branch and update it with remote.
   git checkout master & git pull origin master
4. Switch to development branch and update it with remote.
   git checkout development & git pull origin development
5. merge the master to it.
   git merge master

   At this point your development branch is in sync with master but locally
6. Push the development branch to remote server:
   git push origin developent

   Now you can go to the github and raise PR and see if still shows difference. It should not show any such difference if above steps works with no problem.
7. Now take back your local changes that you stashed in step #2.
   git stash pop
8. Now commit it and push to the development branch and see the PR.

If Everything works fine then it should show the correct diff. `git clean` also might be helpful after step #2.